# ZF3 translate complete html

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, translation

I have following problem.I want to translate my website in different languages. Lets say i want to translate my page in english and german.

I know how to translate single parts of an document by using `translate` ViewHelper.
I know how to individualize links (etc.) by using `translate` and `sprintf`.

But how can i translate the whole html? I have one site where the english structure is completely different to the german structure? I tried to outsource the html into translation file (phparray) but ViewHelpers such as `url` arent recognized.

Any ideas how to get it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the HTML structure is completely different you should load a different template for each and every viewModel per language. So within your controllers:

```
if ($language == 'DE') {
    $viewModel->setTemplate('template/de/index.phtml');
} else {
    $viewModel->setTemplate('template/en/index.phtml');
}
```

You shouldn't use HTML in translation files. Just stick to strings within your translations. Since you already know the HTML structure this shouldn't be a hard thing to setup.